# Sencha Touch and Facebook button

Tags: facebook, sencha-touch

I need to create a button to submit a comment on Face Book wall.

I am using MVC in Sencha touch and in my controller I use a function as

```
facebookComment: function()
{
    --------    
    }
```

This function is to be called when a button is pressed.
Can any body please throw some light on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

i am using following code to post on friends wall see if it is useful to you or not

```
            var postParams = {
                method: 'stream.publish' 
            ,   target_id: friend_id
            ,   display: 'popup'
            ,   message: message
            ,   user_message_prompt: "Post message!"
        }
        FB.api(postParams, function(response) { 
                if(response.error_code || !response) { 
                 to handle error    
                } 
        });
```

or refer this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you should already be using the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). Then just issue a `HTTP POST` request to the `feed` connection of the current user using the `FB.api()` method with the `message` field set to your comment:

```
var body = comment_var;
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

Obviously, should be taking care of the user login status (maybe using the method [`FB.getLoginStatus()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)).